# How can I alter a field group programmatically?

Tags: 10

How can I alter a field group description programmatically?  If I dump the $form variable in my implementation of hook_form_alter, my fields are in the array, but my field groups are not.  What function do I need to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field group has a bunch of its own hooks, listed in the field_group.api.php file within the module.

To alter the form element(s) you can use `hook_field_group_form_process_alter()`, e.g.:

```
function MODULE_field_group_form_process_alter(array &$element, &$group, &$complete_form) {
  $element['#description'] = $foo;
}
```

Comment: Yep, it can be done in hook_field_group_form_process_alter() by setting $element['#description'].

Comment: Great, thanks for following up. Completed the answer with that info